Sound not working on KDE Arch; Requires module-gsetting PulseAudio module
I've been using the KDE Desktop Environment on Arch on an old laptop, and recently, KDE hasn't been able to detect the speakers. Instead I get the message Requires module-gsetting PulseAudio module.
Before this the audio was working perfectly, and I haven't done anything that would disrupt this. Occasionally, I would run some commands along the lines of pacman -S gsettings-qt pulseaudio-gsettings, and sometimes it would fix it, other times, not.
Crucially, the speakers still work, and the mpv command line tool can still play videos and audio perfectly fine. When I uninstall pulseaudio and install pipewire, it only results in more problems, so I want to stick with pulseaudio.
Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

do you have gsettings-desktop-schemas installed?

yes, and I reinstalled it again (just to be safe) but to no avail
